# should I set T-SQL command timeout back to default?

Tags: t-sql, ado.net

I hope this question is not too stupid. I have a long process t-sql command in my ADO.Net.  I would like to increase the command timeout (please see below).

```
 cmd.CommandTimeout = 600; // default is 30 sec. increase to 10 mins
 try
 {
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   cmd.CommandTimeout = 30; // set it back
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
    string debug = ex.Message;
    throw ex;
 }
```

Should I set the timeout back to default after the long process is done? I am looking for the best practice.  Thank you :-)

Comment: Aside: If you were planning to reset it, you ought to save the previous value first rather than assume that it was the documented default.

Answer (score 1):

If you re-use the command object, you can add a finally to the try-catch, so it will be reset regardless of the result of the query. (success or exception).

But when you dispose the SqlCommand after you've used it. There's no need to reset the CommandTimeout

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to not reuse the command because you should not be reusing the connection.  Holding a connection is not good for scale.

```
static private dbConnectionString = "CONNECTION DETAILS";  

using (SQLConnection connection = new SQLConnection(dbConnectionString))
{
   try 
   {   
      connection.Open();
      using (SQLCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
      {
          command.CommandTimeout = 600;
          ......
          using(SQLDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
          {
          }
      }
   }
   catch(SQLException ex)
   {
   }
   finally 
   {
      connection.Close();   
   }
}
```